# Ошибка при входе из одного домена в другой через MS SMS

Tags: sql, sql-server

В общем, с машины, которая находится в одном домене я пытаюсь зайти на SQL Server, который находится в другом домене и ловлю такую ошибку:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно пофиксить?

Для входа использую типа аутентификации: Active Directory- Password

Comment: для доменной авторизации, находясь вне домена, студию запускают через `runas /user "domain\user" /netonly "path/to/ssms.exe"` мб и тут куда то копать  ндо в эту сторону? Хотя ошибка то не про это, конечно.

Comment: Это в выполнить прописывать или в CMD? Я думаю, что это должно решить проблему.

Comment: да без разницы. в кмд ошибки хоть видно :)

Comment: Ошибка сменилась на Login failed. Это, как я уже понимаю, права доступа?

Comment: @teran, помогло. Оформи как ответ. Даже Windws аутентификация сработала.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В ситуациях, когда фактически вы подключены к домену (например, через VPN), но сами в домене не авторизованы,  и при этом хотите использовать доменную авторизацию для подключения к SQL Server в SSMS следует запустить среду с явным указанием имени пользователя.

Сделать это можно выполнить команду

```
runas /user:"domain\user" /netonly "path/to/ssms.exe"
```

при этом будет запрошен пароль для входа в домен. Далее эти учетные данные будут использованы при подключении к серверу БД.

Comment: После user обязательно :, иначе команда валится.

Comment: да, конечно, `/user:"domain\user"`